Aligning Text with SF Symbols in SwiftUI Without Using Frame
In code like this, the varying aspect ratios and side margins of SF Symbols cause the starting positions of the text to be misaligned. How can I fix this? I want to avoid setting fixed frames to support Dynamic Type.
Using a Label instead of an HStack is also fine.
I want to vertically align the icons to the center without disrupting their size balance, and also align the starting position of the text.
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "pencil")
                Text("This is Text")
                Spacer()
            }
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "folder")
                Text("This is Text")
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}



This is what I aim for 
It can be achieved by using a Label within a Form.


I think you will need to set a .frame on the images, but you can use a ScaledMetric as the size. This way, it will adapt to different dynamic font sizes.
Here is an elaborated example:
struct LabelExamples: View {
    @ScaledMetric private var imageWidth: CGFloat = 22.0
    @ScaledMetric private var imageHeight: CGFloat = 18.0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                 Image(systemName: "pencil")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: imageWidth, height: imageHeight)
                 Text("This is Text")
                 Spacer()
             }
             HStack {
                 Image(systemName: "folder")
                     .resizable()
                     .scaledToFit()
                     .frame(width: imageWidth, height: imageHeight)
                 Text("This is Text")
                 Spacer()
             }
         }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            LabelExamples()
                .dynamicTypeSize(.xSmall)
            LabelExamples()
                .dynamicTypeSize(.large)
            LabelExamples()
                .dynamicTypeSize(.xxxLarge)
         }
        .frame(width: 200)
    }
}



Thank you for your response!
I wasn’t aware of ScaledMetric, so I really appreciate it.
Looking at the image you provided, the folder icon appears smaller due to the scaleToFit setting, as it is wider than it is tall.
In my image, where I’m using a Form, the folder icon maintains its original size without being shrunk, keeping the balance.
Would it be better to widen the icon and use scaleToFill to achieve this?

@KngwKngw I was using the same size for width and height at first, then I edited the answer to use different sizes, which made it a bit better. I think you just need to tweak the sizes, try making the width larger. I would not use scaledToFill because it could cause the images to overflow the frame.

Oh, this is perfect!! Thank you so much. This is exactly the answer I was looking for. Based on this, I’m going to create a custom Label view.

Pleased to have been able to help! If you think the answer solves the problem, perhaps you could consider accepting it by tapping the checkmark? Thanks ;)

This is a nice solution, but still involves manual tweaking as per the base sizes. Is there really no better way?

@DrMickeyLauer If the image is .scaledToFit() then there's not much tweaking involved, it's probably sufficient if just the height is set on the image. This height needs to be the approximate line height, defined as a scaled metric (as shown). This will work for most symbols without requiring tweaking on an image-by-image basis. However, if you have multiple labels on multiple lines (as here) then by setting the width too, it keeps the icons and text labels aligned. The width therefore needs to be tuned to the widest symbol being shown.

Using it within a Form automatically sets the size and padding, making it the best solution. If I were to implement it myself, I believe this method would be optimal. Incidentally, I found that many of the SF Symbols used by Apple in settings and within apps are fixed in size regardless of text size, so I ended up setting it to a fixed value.
